# Object File is undefined in Internet Explorer 10

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, html, internet-explorer-10, fileapi

I have a problem with supporting File API in Internet Explorer 10. The object File is undefined. I create a sample asp.net mvc 4 project (net Framework 4). My View Index looks like:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Test File API</h2>

@section scripts {
<script type="text/javascript">
  alert(window.File);
</script>
}
```

When I run it local from Visual Studion 2012 and open in IE10 it returns "[object File]".
When I publish project to IIS server it returns "undefined".

In Chrome and Firefox it work correctly.

Why it happen?

Edited:
When I added `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE10" />` in head off _Layout it works.
Thanks to RGraham.

Comment: Check that the server is not changing the target Internet Explorer version using an `X-UA-Compatible` flag

Comment: Are you running .NET 4.0 on the Application Pool?

Comment: In application pool NET Framework version is 4.0.30319

Comment: No. It doesn't work in IE9.

Thanks to @RGraham.

<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE10" /> is solv the problem.